# Custom web font with @import syntax

Tags: css, webfonts

For an email newsletter, I [have to use](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email) the `@import` CSS syntax for custom web fonts. I own all the fonts in woff, eot and ttf.
I know I can define `@font-face` in CSS but how can I use `@import`?

Comment: Or convert everything to an image :(

Comment: Actually if you pass an absolute url to the import declaration (assuming your fonts are served somewhere) then this should work for the browsers that suport it. So you should write a fallback. Something like:     font-family: customFont, Arial, sans-serif; but I don't think you can do this using inline css, which is often preferred for html emails.

Comment: Ah, maybe you can use inline css: <p style="font-family:Custom, Georgia, serif;">paragraph content</p>

Answer (score 1):

Simple...you must set your import in your css file...you shoud write on the first line or above all your css styles.

```
@import "url";
```

> Beware not all email clients support web fonts

[Read more about it - Web Fonts in HTML Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't... Custom fonts do not work within emails unless you're on a mac.

You'd be better off just using default fonts as the time and effort to include these for such a small minority of users really isn't worth the effort.